# mysql table AUTO increment keeps incrementing in steps of instead of 1. Like 41,51,61

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

Even after deleting all rows in the table continues. It continues adding from the last inserted id.
I used this to create my table

```
app.get('/createuserstable', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE TABLE Users(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), username VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Users table created....');
    });
});
```

adding users with a signup route and it keeps incrementing in steps of 10

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    let user = { name: req.body.name, username: req.body.username, email: req.body.email };
    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET?', user, (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${result.insertId}`);
    });
});
```

this is the code that is used the 10 rows of json data

```
app.get('/populate', (req, res) => {
    request({
        url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
        json: true
    }, (err, resp, body) => {
        //res.send(typeof body);
        for (var i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {

            let post = { id: body[i].id, name: body[i].name, username: body[i].username, email: body[i].email };
            let sql = 'INSERT INTO users SET?';
            let query = db.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
            });
        };
        res.send('users data added....')
    });

});
```

Comment: Why bother? An id is just an id, and shouldn't be re-used.

Comment: Are you asking about the continuation, or about the 10-step? Those are two separate things.

Comment: I assume you did check the actual table in pypMyAdmin or something? Can you confirm that those IDs are in fact unused, i.e. that the table doesn't have any rows in between 41 and 51?

Comment: Unless you've inadvertently fiddled with [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), that's probably the expected behaviour.

Comment: Wait wait, a "for loop from a json api"? The simplest explanation is you're requesting the `/signup` route 10 times instead of only once from the client-side, can you show the relevant code?

Comment: @ChrisG I have edited the question to show that code

Comment: Ok, that's node code though. Anyway, what does the actual table look like? Are you getting each user inserted 10 times into the actual table?

Comment: no, it works fine and each user is added once to the table when i call that route. But even after dropping the table and deleting all the users  the problem persists. Even when no users are in the table, it starts from 1 then to 11,21,31.

Comment: Coming back to @ÁlvaroGonzález idea, what's the result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` ?

Comment: @SebastianB. i just checked that it seems there is a property auto_increment_increment and it is set to 10. But how do i change it back to 1

Comment: AFAIK this can set per session, so you could set it per `SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;` for new connections. But If you're working on a larger codebase with others, I would first grep if it's set somewhere to 10 for a reason, AND if you're not the database admin if would ask him/her first because there may be a reason for this step size.

Comment: Its my database, its just a mini task i'm working on. It still hasn't changed the increment value.  Maybe there is stronger command

Comment: Thanks for your help guys @SebastianB. and  chrisg . I was told that cleardb(the database i was using) configured it that way as you said sebastian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal behavior of MySQL and often intended, so that IDs are never re-used, even for deleted records.

If you really need to reset auto-increment counter, you could either:

- emptying whole table at once with `TRUNCATE TABLE users`
- drop and re-create the table with `DROP TABLE users` / `CREATE TABLE users ...`
- `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1`;

See also https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment/

Comment: I don't think this is about resetting the counter; OP says the new IDs are ten apart instead of consecutive numbers.

Comment: Okay but what about the issue of it adding in steps of 10. If the last id is 41,the next id added is 51. I think it has something to do with how i added the first 10 rows with a for loop from  a json api.

Comment: @ChrisG I oversaw that. My answer at least answers the first part of the question ("Even after deleting all rows in the table continues. It continues adding from the last inserted id").  But you're right, the increment by 10 for every consecutive insert could not be explained by my anser. But I'm not sure if the OP really observed IDs incrementing by 10 or if OP expressed himself/herself just inaccurate.

Comment: Okay @PreshyJones, with what library are you inserting (what's `db`)?

Comment: Ok, I'm not that used to the backend ATM. Checked the docs to be sure that there's no magic "bulk insert" triggered by some reason, but the query syntax is correct and the `user` object simple enough.

Are you sure that the handler is called just once? Did you to some logging / debugging? As @ChrisG wrote this is the most probable reason.

Comment: I added 10 rows of data from a json api using a for loop(i'll edit the question to show you). But even after i dropped the table like you suggested, when i created it again the same problem continues.

Answer (score 1):

You've increased the [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) system variable from the default value of `1`  to `10`. Its scope is **Global, Session** so you can either set it for current session or change it for the entire server (the first option used to be restricted prior to MySQL/8.0.18).

If you don't need it at all I suggest you just find the directive in the settings file and comment it out.